# Android redirect to application after clicking a link

Tags: android

I am calling a API which send a message to particular number . The message contain a link
**http://tinyurl.com/opcohlb**

What I want to achieve is ,when user click on the link it will open it in browser and then it has to become back to application automatically.

**I am using the following declaration in my Manifest File.**

```
          <activity
                android:name=".VerificationActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                 android:theme="@style/MyTheme" >
                 <intent-filter>
                      <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                      <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                    <data
                     android:host="tinyurl.com"
                     android:path="/"
                     android:scheme="http" />
                    </intent-filter>
          </activity>
```

but it is not returning to application. Please help me out to achieve the objective.

Comment: Use startActivityForResult method to open the link

Comment: since my link is not static so how can i call that. please provide some help